# Can developer lock other apps in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10

Does Apple allow third party developer lock other app or setup passcode for other apps in iOS10?

If so, what is the best library to do it?

Comment: No, this is not possible in any version of iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Imagine the harm that a malicious developer could cause if that **was** possible. It would spawn a whole family ransomeware apps.

iOS apps are "sandboxed" and can't alter the functioning of the OS or of other apps except in very controlled, specific ways.

The only possible way would be for you to release a suite of apps that have a shared keychain and save an unlock key to the keychain from your "master app" that would be required by the other apps in order for your other apps to function.

That would only work for apps you release however, and Apple might reject apps that were built that way.

Comment: Many thanks Duncan for your information. Much appreciated for the insight.